# How to stop a page that is refreshing every one second if the bootstrap modal is active or on show?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, bootstrap-4

I have two php pages, first page is where I display the data from a MySQL database using Ajax that refreshes every 1 second, the second page contains the php code to fetch the data from the database wherein I have a bootstrap modal that shows the other information of every record.

**First php page:**

```
<div class = "container">
   <div id = "show_MySql_table_data"></div>
</div>

<script>
//Ajax script for displaying the record every 1 second
 var interval = 1000;
 function displayData() {
   $.ajax ({
    url: "details_info.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {},
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
        $("#show_MySql_table_data").html(data);
    },
    complete: function (data) {
        setTimeout(displayData, interval);
    }       
   });
  }
   setTimeout(displayData, interval);
  </script>
```

**Second php page:**

```
<?php
$cn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testdb");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblsample";
$result = mysqli_query($cn,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $name = $rows['Name'];
        $address = $rows['Address'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $name . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $address . "</td>";
        echo "<td><button class = 'toggleDetailsModal btn btn-info'>More Info</button></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
?>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class = "modal" id = "detailsModal">
<div class = "modal-dialog">
    <div class = "modal-content">
        <div class = "modal-header">
            <h5 class = "modal-title">Details</h5>
            <button class = "close" data-dismiss = "modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class = "modal-body">
            More Information here....
        </div>
        <div class = "modal-footer">
            <button class = "btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-dismiss = "modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script> //this is included in the second php page
$(".toggleDetailsModal").on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#detailsModal").modal('show');
});
</script>
```

What's happening is when I click More Info button, the modal automatically close and my screen was grayed out.

**How can I stop the automatic refreshing of the page (every 1 second) when I click the More Info button and if the Modal is active or in show mode?**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: setInterval/clearInterval ?

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to determine whether the modal is open or closed, one option is to hook into the bootstrap modal's events:

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events
>
> `show.bs.modal`
>
> This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called. If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the relatedTarget property of the event.
>
> `hide.bs.modal`
>
> This event is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been called.

Adding to your existing code:

```
var modalActive = false;
$("#detailsModal").on("show.bs.modal", function() {
    modalActive = true;
});
$("#detailsModal").on("hide.bs.modal", function() {
    modalActive = false;
});

function displayData() {
    if (!modalActive) {
        $.ajax ...
    } else {
        setTimeout(displayData, interval);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, when I applied your code above it doesn't show any records from the database? Please correct me if I'm wrong, I added those codes in the first php page, thanks again :)